# Anyone knows any Linq to XQuery implementation?

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, xquery

the question is basically in the title. Also if anyone has started some kind of implementation but never finished it and is willing to share it, I'm interested! :)
Or if it is being used internally in an open-source project...

Comment: Just out of curiosity : what can you do with XQuery that you can't do with Linq to XML ? (sorry if that's obvious, I have no experience with XQuery).

Comment: XQuery integration in SQLServer....

Comment: Linq to XML is based on IEnumerable i.e. all in memory and greedy. You can't really use it to query xml databases (Marklogic, Berkeley DB, etc). A Linq to XQuery provider is similar to Linq to SQL where the expression tree gets translated into XQuery code and then executed against the XML database.

Comment: @CosminOnea Actually IEnumerable has nothing to do with why LINQ to XML ends up all in memory, it's because XElement and XDocument load the entire XML content. Have a look at the XStreamingElement Class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx. The problem that you will have with XStreamingElement is that you'll be trading your memory consumption problem for time and IO as repeated queries will still hit the disk. For really large stuff this method breaks down, too.

Comment: @CosminOnea I'm guessing that what you really want is something with a low memory footprint, that can build and use indexes to speed queries against the XML DB as well, yet still allows you to use Linq. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found this while looking for something similar.

Quoting the other [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sqlxml/thread/d5493004-8291-488b-b5d7-634d4634ce5b):

> Incase anyone is interested.
>   I'm building a Linq provider for XML columns in sql server.
>
> The Linq provider will translate the query into sql server compatible XQuery code.
>
> [Info](http://rogeralsing.com/2011/03/02/linq-to-sqlxml-projections/)
>
> [Code](https://github.com/rogeralsing/linq-to-sqlxml)
>
> This allows you to use sql server like a schema free document DB a'la NoSQL.
>   Altough the usecase here is not scale but rather the joy of persisting unmapped entities and versioned entities.

Comment: Original post is in: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sqlxml/thread/d5493004-8291-488b-b5d7-634d4634ce5b